# get friend list in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table like here :

```
friend : (userid , friendid)
```

so , if `user_a` is friend with `user_b` , I will load the row below into table

```
user_a , user_b
```

and **I DO NOT** insert `usar_b , user_a` into   table .

so how can I get friend list of user_b with mysql query ?

Comment: Why is the question tagged with both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you want userA's friends
You need to get all the friends of userA, Union it with all the users whose friend is userA.

Assuming that userA's ID is `1001` the query will be

```
select UserID from Friends
where FriendID = 1001
Union All
select FriendID from Friends
where UserID = 1001
```

Comment: And you can (safely) use `UNION ALL` as the OP says that he is storing only one of the two pairs.

Comment: @ypercube good point noticed, I added it to my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `(t1.id<t2.id)` allows us to include only one pair `a,b` and exclude `b,a`

```
select t1.userid user1, t2.userid user2
FROM friends t1
JOIN friends t2 ON (t1.friend=t2.id) and (t1.id<t2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.user,a.friend from 
friend a,friend b
where a.user=b.user and
a.friend=b.friend and a.user<>b.friend
and a.friend<>b.user
```

try this